# Hashes imported line by line in a txt file are not correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, md5, hashlib

I'm working on a small dictionary hash cracker.
I know I need multiprocessing, but I'm just testing it as of now.
My problem is not that I get an error; its that passwords (or keywords) in my dictionary file are not hashed correctly.

```
import hashlib

print(" _               _                           _             ")
print("| |             | |                         | |            ")
print("| |__   __ _ ___| |__     ___ _ __ __ _  ___| | _____ _ __ ")
print("| '_ \ / _` / __| '_ \   / __| '__/ _` |/ __| |/ / _ \ '__|")
print("| | | | (_| \__ \ | | | | (__| | | (_| | (__|   <  __/ |   ")
print("|_| |_|\__,_|___/_| |_|  \___|_|  \__,_|\___|_|\_\___|_|   ")
print("")
print("Made By IronKey | python 3.7 ")
hashed = input("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD TO RECOVER: ")
wordlist = input("enter your dictionary: ")
print("")

with open(wordlist) as passList:
    for i in passList:
        hash1 = hashlib.md5(i.encode())
        hash1.hexdigest()
        print(hash1.hexdigest())
        if str(hash1.hexdigest()) == str(hashed):
            print("password is cracked: " + i)
            break

print("")
input("press enter to leave")
```

example input: b81e70651fb13d7d7051cc1684c0f91e (the hash for Password234)
example output (if Passowrd234 is in the dictionary file): password is cracked: Password234

actual output: hash for Password234 is completely different and it returns its comparison as wrong!

Comment: Please provide an example input with corresponding expected output and actual output.

Comment: sure leme get it

Comment: `for i in passList` -- `i` still has its trailing newline here. Try `hash1 = hashlib.md5(i.strip().encode())`

Comment: also probably pick a more descriptive name? `for line in passfile` or something?

Comment: also worth noting `hash1.hexdigest()` and `hashed` are both strings -- it's not necessary to cast them to string before comparing.

Comment: ok leme try it really quick

Comment: I think that possibly could have worked I just have a small bug now

Comment: that completely worked @AdamSmith thanks a ton